# REST only use get and post

Tags: json, rest, jackson

Since not all client browsers support put and delete, is it good practice to only use 'get' and 'post' for all crud operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically when you use a restful interface, its not intended for a browser...its intended for client software such as Javascript, Desktop applications, or 3-rd party interfaces.

Comment: @Cliber104, agreed, but to support wider audiences, arent just use get and post are enough?

Comment: Yes...it will still work, but full Restful interfaces require all the Http Methods to work

Comment: Web browsers are actually one of the best examples of RESTful clients. REST interfaces do not require the use of all the Http methods.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  However, your framework should still support proper PUT and DELETE requests that come in.  Ruby on Rails emulates these requests by using a special parameter to POST requests -- the framework then routes the request to a PUT/DELETE handler as appropriate.

Comment: so your suggestion is need to force client to emulate put and delete. I understand that. but that will give client extra work right?

Comment: @cometta: Not necessarily -- clients that support the methods (such as C#/Python/etc bindings) can use them.  You only supply the emulation POST keys to browsers, since not all browsers support PUT/DELETE.

Answer (score 1):

See the first entry in this faq page:  http://code.google.com/p/implementing-rest/wiki/FAQ